# A proof of a combinatorial identity

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

Suppose $k \leq m \leq n$. Show that

\begin{align*}
{{n-k}\choose{n-m}}=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{\min(k,\text{ n-m})} (-1)^{i}{{k}\choose{i}}{{n-i}\choose{m}}
\end{align*}

I'm having troubles with this one. Any (elegant) solutions?

Comment: Check the coefficients of $\, x^k (1+x)^{n-k}=(1+x)^n (1-\frac{1}{1+x})^k$ . Left side: $(1+x)^{n-k}=...$ sum with counter $m$ , Right side: (1) $(1-\frac{1}{1+x})^k=...$ sum with counter $i$ , Multiplication of the result of (1) with $(1+x)^n$ , (2) $(1+x)^{n-i}=...$ sum with counter $m$

Comment: Sorry, this is not very clear to me. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: $(1+a)^n$ gives a sum with binominal coefficients which you have to know. And then: Step by step what I've written. E.g.: Which sum is $x^k (1+x)^{n-k}$ ?

Comment: Very helpful answer. Note that this also solves my other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2457320/proving-an-interesting-falling-factorial-identity), since some of the terms in x (those with a power less than $k$) in the RHS expansion have to be zero.

Comment: So, your question is answered or it is still something missing ? :-)

Comment: Yes. However, in relationship to the factorial identity: this method seems to give a solution to my other question only for when the factorials are a product of positive numbers (in this case: $n-m>k$). Is there a way around this, such that we can use this method to provide a solution to the more general identity?

Comment: The case $\,n-m\geq k\,$ is clear. But for $\,n-m < k\,$ please check $\,\displaystyle {\binom {n-i} m}$ : $\,$ With $\,i=1...k\,$ it's $\,0\,$ for all $\,i>n-m\,$. Therefore $\,k\,$ in the sum symbol can be simply substituted by $\,\min(k,n-m)\,$ .

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer based upon generating functions. It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ in a series. This way we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i= 0}^{\min\{k,\text{ n-m}\}}}&\color{blue}{ (-1)^{i}\binom{k}{i}\binom{n-i}{m}}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^\infty(-1)^i[z^i](1+z)^k[u^m](1+u)^{n-i}\tag{1}\\
> &=[u^m](1+u)^n\sum_{i=0}^\infty\left(-\frac{1}{1+u}\right)^i[z^i](1+z)^k\tag{2}\\
> &=[u^m](1+u)^n\left(1-\frac{1}{1+u}\right)^k\tag{3}\\
> &=[u^{m-k}](1+u)^{n-k}\tag{4}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\binom{n-k}{m-k}}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the *coefficient of* operator twice. We also set the upper limit to $\infty$ without changing anything since we are adding zeros only.
- In (2) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator. We also do some rearrangements as preparation for the next step.
- In (3) we apply the substitution rule of the *coefficient of* operator with $z:=-\frac{1}{(1+u)}$
  \begin{align*}
  A(u)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k u^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty u^k [z^k]A(z)
  \end{align*}
- In (4) we do some simplifications and apply  the rule 
  $$
  [u^{m-k}]A(u)=[u^m]u^kA(u)
  $$
- In (5) we select the coefficient of $[u^{m-k}]$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{\min(k,n-m)}(-1)^i\binom{k}{i}\binom{n-i}{m}
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-m}(-1)^i\binom{k}{i}\binom{n-i}{n-m-i}\tag1\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-m}(-1)^{n-m}\binom{k}{i}\binom{-m-1}{n-m-i}\tag2\\
&=(-1)^{n-m}\binom{k-m-1}{n-m}\tag3\\[3pt]
&=\binom{n-k}{n-m}\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$
$(2)$: $\binom{-n}{k}=(-1)^k\binom{k+n-1}{k}$
$(3)$: Vandermonde's Identity
$(4)$: $\binom{-n}{k}=(-1)^k\binom{k+n-1}{k}$