# Proving an interesting (falling) factorial identity

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, factorial, combinatorial-proofs

Let $(x)_{n}=x(x-1)\ldots(x-n+1)$ for $n>0$ and $(x)_0=1$.

Prove that if $n<k$, then
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i {{k}\choose{i}}(x-i)_n=0
\end{equation}

Any thoughts? Note that $n=0$ is trivial since you are summing alternating binomial coefficients.

Comment: $x$ is a constant?

Comment: Yes. You can think of the LHS as a polynomial in $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For example:*

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!} \sum\limits_{i=0}^k (-1)^i {\binom k i} (x-i)_n = \sum\limits_{i=0}^k (-1)^i {\binom k i} \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!} (x-i)_n =$

$\displaystyle = \sum\limits_{i=0}^k (-1)^i {\binom k i} (1+z)^{x-i} = z^k (1+z)^{x-k} = \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty {\binom {x-k} j} z^{k+j} $

Comparing the coefficients of $\,z^n\,$ proofs the claim.

Comment: What about convergence? Does $(1+z)^{x-i} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!}(x-i)_n$ always hold?

Comment: Only for $|z|<1$ . But a value of $z$ is unimportant, it's only necessary that $(1+z)^{x-i}$ can be developed into a Taylor series around $z=0$ . Here it's called *binomial series* . (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series , see binomial series)

Comment: Yes, indeed. Btw, if you are interested: I will use this small proof in a paper that I'm writing. If you want, I mention your name in the acknowledgements.

Comment: Thanks, but: Everything that is written here in this forum, is for free use. There is no need to mention someone. :-) --- Note: You can mention *Wikipedia* .